# Developping a long quadratic form like $(x-y-z-\mu)^t\Sigma^{-1}(x-y-z-\mu)$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Is there a way to some how develop a long quadratic form ? Maybe something like : 
$(x-y-z-\mu)^t\Sigma^{-1}(x-y-z-\mu)= (x-\mu)^t\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu) - (y+z)^t\Sigma^{-1}(y+z)$

or is there another way to break a long transpose ? 
Thanks !

Comment: I think you're asking for ways to rewrite $(a+b)^tC(a+b)$. The distributive law gives $$(a+b)^tC(a+b)=(a^t+b^t)(Ca+Cb)=a^tCa+a^tCb+b^tCa+b^tCb$$ So you're always going to get "cross-terms" like $a^tCb$, and the kind of rewrite you ask for can't happen.

Comment: thanks @GerryMyerson, that's what I was asking about.